# What group is being referred to when a qualifier is left out?

Tags: grammar

What group is being referred to when a qualifier is left out?

For example in the sentence "Women are better drivers than men." does women mean all women, most women, typical (average) woman or something else?

"Muffins are healthy." All of them? A typical muffin?

Comment: It makes a difference whether it's singular or plural. These are [generic noun phrases](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html).

Comment: When used in everyday conversation, these are examples of hyperbole. Here, [over]generalisations. 'Muffin' is ill-defined in any case; a typical American will have a different mental image than a typical Brit will.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Where's the hyperbole?  What does it mean to you if someone says "Women are better drivers than men?" To me it clearly means the average woman. "Muffins are healthy." to me means the typical muffin. Is that incorrect grammar?

Comment: The statement interpreted precisely must mean 'women are without exception better drivers than men', but it is very rarely intended to carry this sense. The hyperbole is in using what is clearly an overgeneralisation in a way intended to be interpreted pragmatically in the sense 'the average female driver is a better driver than the average male driver' (**or** 'women on average make better drivers', not quite the same). This is not a matter of correct/incorrect grammar or logic, but on pragmatics, the often loose (but acceptable) ways in which English is used. Outside the Law Courts.

Comment: Ok, got it. It's grammatically poor but typically interpreted as typical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All? Average? Typical? It's completely ambiguous. What is meant will be determined solely by the speaker, and because it is ambiguous, confusion abounds.

I think what is most often meant though is "in general" or "as a general rule." Say I were to hear someone say, "Flowers are lovely, aren't they?" My first thought should *not* be that *all* flowers are lovely, but that as a general rule, if you come across a flower, it's likely to be lovely. You can't even assign a numerical average to it, as if you're disallowed to say the statement if it falls beneath a percentile. Maybe 80% of the flowers they encounter are lovely, and that's enough. Probably not 51%, in which they'd notice that almost every other flower wasn't lovely.

It's simply to be taken as a general rule, which may or may not be broken. To get any more precise, you absolutely need the qualifiers.

Comment: Exactly ... in general. Doesn't "in general" mean typical?

Comment: That depends on what "typical means." I'd say "in general" or "typical" is what most often is meant, but there is still always ambiguity.